# Partition a Spark DataFrame based on values in an existing column into a chosen number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, grouping, partitioning

I would like to partition a Spark DataFrame into an even number of partitions based on an index column before writing to a file. I would like to control how many partitions to create based on the size of the DataFrame and then use then when writing to Parquet file using `partitionBy`.

Having an example DataFrame:

```
 i     b
 0    11
 1     9
 2    13
 3     2
 4    15
 5     3
 6    14
 7    16
 8    11
 9     9
 10   17
 11   10
```

Assuming that I would like to create 4 partitions based on values in column `i` then the partitions would correspond to the values assigned to column `g`:

```
g    i     b
0    0    11
0    1     9
0    2    13
1    3     2
1    4    15
1    5     3
2    6    14
2    7    16
2    8    11
3    9     9
3   10    17
3   11    10
```

What is the preferred way of doing this in Spark?

Comment: Assuming you want 4 partitions written out

Comment: Answer is considered as ...? It is a good question although I am curious as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation seems a little hard to follow, and making some assumptions on the question - i.e. it would like 4 or rather N files(?) as output with an ascending approach on the id stated as column "i", hereby my own **Spark 2.4** adapted example that takes 20 records and splits them into 4 evenly ranged partitions and then writes these out. Let's go:

```
val list = sc.makeRDD((1 to 20)).map((_, 1,"2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",1,2,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))

val df = list.toDF("customer_id", "dummy", "report_date", "date", "value_1", "value_2", "dummy_string")
df.show(false)
```

Showing a few entries only:

```
+-----------+-----+-----------+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
|customer_id|dummy|report_date|date      |value_1|value_2|dummy_string              |
+-----------+-----+-----------+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
|1          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|2          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|3          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|4          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|5          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|6          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|7          |1    |2019-01-01 |2019-01-01|1      |2      |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
...
```

Then - including some extra sorting for good measure - this not necessary, working with all formats:

```
df.repartitionByRange(4, $"customer_id")
  .sortWithinPartitions("customer_id", "date", "value_1")
  .write
  .parquet("/tmp/SOQ6")
```

This gave 4 files as in the picture below:

[image]

You can see 4 files and the first and last parts naming are evident. Running:

```
val lines = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/SOQ6/part-00000-tid-2518447510905190948-a81455f6-6c0b-4e02-89b0-57dfddf1fb97-1200-c000.snappy.parquet")
val words = lines.collect
lines.count
```

reveals 5 records, and the content which is ordered consecutively as per the dataframe.

```
lines: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [customer_id: int, dummy: int ... 5 more fields]
 words: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX], [2,1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX], [3,1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX], [4,1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX], [5,1,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,1,2,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX])
res11: Long = 5
```

Ran this on all the files, but only show one.

> **Final comments**
>
> Whether this is a good idea is a different story, e.g. think of non-broadcast JOINs that is an issue.
>
> In addition I would obviously not hard-code the 4, but apply some formula for N to to be applied to the partitionByRange! E.g.:
>
> ```
> val N = some calculation based on counts in DF and your cluster 
> val df2 = df.repartition(N, $"c1", $"c2")
> ```
>
> You have to test the DF Writer as the documentation is not entirely clear.
>
> Checked on EMR Cluster with 2M records, 4 files as well in terms of output.

Answer (score 0):

## DataFrame Partition Based On Columns and Size In Spark

### Step 1: We are writing a python function for that

def partition_dataframe(df, col_name, col_name2, size1, size2):
df.repartition(2).write.partitionBy(col_name,col_name2).mode("append")
.save("/fileStore/tables/output_part")
return df

### Step 2: Register UDF

partition_dataframe = udf(partition_dataframe)

### Step 3: Pass Argument to UDF

partitioned_df = partition_dataframe(df, 'device', 'events', 1024, 1024)

### Step 4: Check partitioned files using following command and location which we added in python function

%fs ls /fileStore/tables/output_part_size1

**Note:** Here df is DataFrame, 'device' and 'events' are column names in DataFrame and 1024 is the size for partition which is in KB.

We can modify function according to our need like we can change number of partition, here we used repartition(2)